# Spinning menu button HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I tried making a spinning menu button for a website. I want it to spin and change its content when clicked, then turn back when it's clicked again

Here is my code :

```js
//Shops

const shopButtons = document.querySelector('.shopButtons')

//Shop animation on click

shopButtons.addEventListener('click', () => shopButtons.classList.toggle('openMenu'));
```

```css
.shopButtons {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  transition: .75s;
  transform: rotate(-359deg);
}

.shopButtons.openMenu {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 120);
}

.shopButtons::after {
  content: '\1F6D2';
  color: white;
  font-size: 3em;
  transition: background-color .75s;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.openMenu {
  transition: .75s;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.openMenu::after {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 120);
  color: white;
  content: '\00D7';
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
  <title>Website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="shopButtons" id="mainShop"></button>

  <script src="../scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I think it works pretty well (not sure if the code is optimized though), but I am struggling to make it so the shopping cart icon only appears when the button isn't rotating.

As of right now it works when the menu is opened, but on exit, the shopping cart appears before the rotation animation is over

Is there a simple way to do this ?

I have tried delaying the rotation animation, but this only lead to a very slow animation. I also tried delaying the image change using JavaScript, but it wasn't functional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that you are rotating the entire button, rather than the icons. So the shopping cart will always spin.

What I did here is removed the transformation from the `.shopButtons` button. Then added a 360deg rotation to just the `.openMenu` button.

Maybe this is an easy solution for you.

```js
//Shops

const shopButtons = document.querySelector('.shopButtons')

//Shop animation on click

shopButtons.addEventListener('click', () => shopButtons.classList.toggle('openMenu'));
```

```css
.shopButtons {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.shopButtons.openMenu {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 120);
}

.shopButtons::after {
  content: '\1F6D2';
  color: white;
  font-size: 3em;
  transition: background-color .75s;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.openMenu {
  transition: .75s;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.openMenu::after {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 120);
  color: white;
  content: '\00D7';
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
  <title>Website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="shopButtons" id="mainShop"></button>

  <script src="../scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```